# How to highlight an event that is about to be deleted from FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, ruby-on-rails-5

To help the user see what is changing in their calendar I would like to add a highlight effect to events that are about to deleted.

I have tried to use the: eventDestroy callback but this callback seems to be called for every rendered event on the calendar and not for the event that is about to be deleted.

currently I'm doing the following which works but is not very good code:

destroy.js.erb

```
var targetEvents = $("#calendar").fullCalendar("clientEvents", '<%= "user_event_#{@user_event.id}" %>');
targetEvents[0].deleted = true;
targetEvents[0].color = "white";
$("#calendar").fullCalendar("updateEvent", targetEvents[0]);

setTimeout(function(){
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', '<%= "user_event_#{@user_event.id}" %>');
},3000); 

$('.modal').modal('hide');
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('#remote-container').empty();
});
```

My css:

```
  @keyframes yellowfade {
    from { 
      color: black;
      background: yellow;      
      }
    to   { 
      color: transparent;
      background: transparent; 
      }
  }

  .deleted {
      color: white;
      animation-name: yellowfade;
      animation-duration: 2.5s;
  }
```

full_calendar.js

```
var initialize_calendar;
initialize_calendar = function() {
  $('#calendar').each(function(){
    var calendar = $(this);
    calendar.fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: 'prev, next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay'
      },
      selectable: true,
      selectHelper: true,
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true,
      contentHeight: 'auto',
      eventSources: ['/registration/user_events.json'],

      eventRender: function(event, eventElement) {
          if (event.recurring) {
              eventElement.find("div.fc-content").addClass('recurring');
          }
          if (event.allDay) {
            eventElement.find("div.fc-content").addClass('all_day');
          }
          if (event.deleted) {
            eventElement.find("div.fc-content").addClass('deleted');
          }
      },

      displayEventEnd: true,

      select: function(start, end) {
        start_date = moment(start).format("YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm");
        end_date = end.subtract(1, "days");
        end_date = moment(end_date).format("YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm");
        $.getScript('/registration/user_events/new?starting='+start_date+'&ending='+end_date, function() {});

        calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
      },

      eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
        update(event);
      },

      eventResize: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
        update(event);
      },

      eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
        $.getScript(event.edit_url, function() {});
      },

    });
  })
};
```

I would prefer to just be able to use a callback and jquery highlight effect but I can't figure out how.

Any ideas?

Comment: sorry it's not very clear...how are you triggering the deletion of an event, exactly?

Comment: $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', '<%= "user_event_#{@user_event.id}" %>');

Comment: I saw that but no, I mean how does the code which deletes the events get executed? Some kind of user action?

Comment: Correct. There is a modal form that has a button.  User clicks 'delete this event' and the id of the event is sent to the controller delete action.

Comment: if you can get hold of the right HTML element in fullCalendar then you could run a jQuery fade on it, and since that allows you to specify a callback to run when it's complete, you could then run the fullcalendar deleteEvent method once the fade has completed.

Comment: Thanks ADyson the problem with FullCalendar as far as I can see is the elements on the page are all classes. There are no ID's that can be used to determine the element being deleted.

Comment: @chell are you able to create a working example? snippet/fiddle/codepen... it will help understand the issue and find a solution.

Comment: Highlight means you want to delete events which will delete in next 24 hours or you are marking as delete ?

Comment: Means I will delete the event immediately. I delete the database object in the controller but I can't seem to target the exact object on the Calendar.